# When using the preposition "for" should it be followed with the subjective or objective case?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, grammatical-case

> The activity we engaged in was good for she and I.

or

> The activity we engaged in was good for us both.

or

> The activity we engaged in was good for her and me.

Answer (score 7):

Prepositions in standard English take the prepositional (objective) case.

> The activity we engaged in was for her and me.

Comment: +1. But just a cautionary note to readers not to confuse preposition "for" with conjunction "for": *I bought food for us to eat*, but *I bought food, for I was hungry* :-)

Answer (score 1):

"Her and me" or "both of us", but not "she and I".

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to omit each pronoun in turn and see what fits

> The activity we engaged in was good for her

and

> The activity we engaged in was good for me

hence

> The activity we engaged in was good for her and me.

though

> The activity we engaged in was good for us.

can sometimes be used (where "us" is unambiguous) to avoid the problem.

or

> The activity she and I engaged in was good for us.

(because "I engaged in an activity" and "she engaged in an activity")